# Converting an absolute Path to a relative one

Tags: rust

I've this code that I use in some tool, and I wonder if it can be improved:

```
fn make_relative(target_dir: &Path, current_dir: &Path) -> PathBuf {
    if target_dir.is_relative() {
        return target_dir.into();
    }
    let mut result = PathBuf::new();
    let mut path_before_current_dir = PathBuf::new();
    let mut after_current_dir = false;
    for component in target_dir.components() {
        if after_current_dir {
            result.push(component.as_os_str());
        } else {
            path_before_current_dir.push(component.as_os_str());
        }
        if path_before_current_dir == current_dir {
            after_current_dir = true;
        }
    }
    if result.to_string_lossy().is_empty() {
        ".".into()
    } else {
        result
    }
}
```

I also wonder if it's okay that I return PathBuf, instead of Path.

Comment: This function already exists in the standard library: [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix).